# How to specify Roslyn method parameters

Tags: c#, parameters, constructor, roslyn

I've got the following code, but I do not think the parameter is quite correct. How do I actually use the Roslyn code generation bits in order to specify a parameter? Note that it must also be an `array`. Thanks!

```
using static SyntaxFactory;
using static SyntaxKind;
using static LanguageVersion;
// ...
MemberDeclarationSyntax GeneratePrivateBytesCtor()
    => ConstructorDeclaration(Descriptor.TypeIdentifier)
        .WithModifiers(SyntaxTokenList.Create(Token(PrivateKeyword)))
        .AddParameterListParameters(ParseParameterList("byte[] bytes").Parameters.Single())
        .WithInitializer(ConstructorInitializer(BaseConstructorInitializer)
            .AddArgumentListArguments(
                Argument(IdentifierName("bytes"))
            )
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of digging and some tinkering, I wonder if this is a better approach?

```
const string bytes = nameof(bytes);
const SyntaxKind arrayType = SyntaxKind.ArrayType;

var bytesSyntax = Parameter(Identifier(bytes))
    .WithModifiers(Create(Token(arrayType)))
    .WithType(ParseTypeName(typeof(byte).FullName))
    ;
```

Again, assuming certain static using statements.

Or, perhaps even something like this:

```
var bytesSyntax = Parameter(Identifier(bytes))
    .WithType(ParseTypeName(typeof(byte[]).FullName))
    ;
```

Based loosely on assumptions from distant experience with *Reflection**, wherein I seem to recall that "arrays" are identified as a type "modifier", along these lines. I could be mistaken there; it's been a little while, but here I find I want to declare the parameter as `byte[]` quite literally.

Thoughts?